# Looking for zsh completion file for osX native commands

Tags: mac-osx, zsh

I've been digging deep into what actually comes with osX in /usr/bin and especially /usr/libexec.

Quite good stuff really, although the command syntax is a bit.. odd.

Let me direct the curious to the command that made me think of this:

```
networksetup -printcommands
```

I can not think of a command that better illustrates the need for good  completion.

```
security -h
```

perhaps, but those commands have a familiar easy-to-read format.

I beseech the community, please point me to a place where I can find such a thing. I never type them right, and I ache for tab completion for this

Anyone have any idea where I could grab something? I'd prefer to stand on the shoulders of giants instead of trying to make a zsh/bash completion script leap into the world, ready for battle, like Athena, from my forehead.

I am no Zeus when it comes to compctl.  Not at all.

Comment: compctl is old school. zstyle nicer.  Gonna try, as I am all alone  out here apparently ;)

Comment: It's not that much nicer.  Got the basics for networksetup.  Odd, I would ordinarily hate zsh by now, but the very little I dug out of that byzantine manpage makes zsh so much sweeter... How I wish I could walk away from this sort of thing....

Comment: +1: Mind sharing what you have so far?

Comment: Certainly. At least it tab completes on the myriad switches... I'll clean it up and upload this am.

Answer (score 3):

This project has a number of completions for Mac-specific commands (neither of the two you mentioned, but it does have others like defaults, hdiutil, launchctl, mdls, open, and others), as well as a lot of other command-line functions and utilities:

http://code.google.com/p/zsh-templates-osx/

There's a lot of Mac development and system utilities that don't have completions defined yet (libtool, pkgutil, otool; the ones you mentioned); hopefully the project maintainer is active and accepts contributions.